# Does a group with exponential growth always have a hyperbolic subgroup which has exponential growth?

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

> Does a group with exponential growth always have a hyperbolic subgroup which has exponential growth?

There is a heuristic theorem.
When the group has a hyperbolic subgroup, by Tits' Alternative theorem, the subgroup if doesn't contain degree 2 free group then it is virtually solvable.

Exponential growth and hyperbolicity have overlap to some extent.

I wonder to what extent can this question be answered.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Now it is clear. Sorry for that.

Comment: OK, the answer is yes, because the trivial group is hyperbolic.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I guess I want this subgroup to have exponential growth.

Comment: There is also such an alternative (known a bit before Tits', and significantly easier) for f.g. solvable groups, whence Derek's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polycyclic groups that are not virtually nilpotent, such as $\langle x,y,z \mid xy=yz, x^y=z, z^y=yz \rangle$ have exponential growth, but they have no non-elementary hyperbolic subgroups (i.e. all of their hyperbolic subgroups are virtually cyclic).

Comment: Could you please give the definition of $^y=$?

Comment: $z^y$ means $y^{-1}zy$.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see why it is not nilpotent?

Comment: It has trivial centre.

Comment: And why are all hyperbolic subgroups virtually cyclic?

Comment: Because hyperbolic groups have no subgroups that are isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}^2$.

Comment: Why can not  such Polycyclic group itself be a hyperbolic group?

Comment: A polycyclic group that is not virtually cyclic has a subgroup isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}^2$, and hyperbolic groups have no such subgroups. The same applies more generally to solvable groups that are not virtually cyclic - the answer by Mark Sapir to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343367)

Answer (score -1):

I totally agree with what Derek said. I think it is a good answer which helps me understand better polynomial growth. The first example I learn in geometric group theorem which is polycyclic but not nilpotent is $Z^2 \rtimes  _ {\varphi}Z$ where ${\varphi}$ is an isomorphism of ${Z}^2$ that has an eigenvalue bigger than 1.